# Windows Media Player - Hide player after it is done playing

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am creating a game, I want to display a short tutorial video to the player after they have registered. I am using a windows media player control. I don't know how to hide the video after it has finished playing ? 
I tried using the following:

```
WMP.Ctlcontrols.play();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
WMP.Dispose();
```

I am using the disposing as a way to close down the video. I tried hide and close as well but they close the video before it's finished playing, after 3 seconds.

Comment: If you added Media player control to the form, you don't need to dispose it manually. It will be disposed after you closed the form.

Comment: I am using the disposing as a way to close down the video. I tried hide and close as well but they close the video before it's finished playing.

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the player when the video finished playing?

Comment: You can handle [PlayStateChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460(v=vs.85).aspx) event of control and check if `e.newState==1`, it means the playing has been stopped. Then you can hide the control.

Comment: It's working now, Thank you very much .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle [`PlayStateChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmp/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-playstatechange?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event of control and check if `e.newState==1`, it means the playing has been stopped. Then you can hide the control.

```
void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, 
    AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if(e.newState== 1) // Stopped
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Hide();
}
```